# Insert a row of grid into datacontext

Tags: c#, linq

Looking for an example in linq about how to insert a row of a gridview into datacontext.

Answer (score 1):

First - you'd need a typed object. This will obviously be easier if your gridview is already data-bound. You can use [InsertOnSubmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx) (new record) or [Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548978.aspx) (update existing) to associate a record with a data-context. Alternatively, bind to object you got from the data-context in the first place. One simple way of doing that is via [GetNewBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534545.aspx) (how well this works depends on the scenario).

If that doesn't help, perhaps explain more about your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

```
using (WebShop.DDFAdminwebshopDataContext db = new WebShop.DDFAdminwebshopDataContext())

        {
            var productstags = from productstag in db.sk_productstags where productstag.productid == _productid
                               && productstag.tagid == _tagid select productstag;


            if (productstags.Count() == 0) {

                WebShop.DDFAdmin.sk_productstags entProductTag = new WebShop.DDFAdmin.sk_productstags();
                entProductTag.productid = _productid;
                entProductTag.tagid = _tagid;

                db.sk_productstags.InsertOnSubmit(entProductTag);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }

        }
```